# Error building GDAL for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, build, gdal

I've been trying to build GDAL for iOS for a while. Using the MikL shell script from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643898/incorporating-gdal-ogr-into-an-ios-project-a-quick-guide), I managed to start the building process, but it always gives me the same error:

```
In file included from hugefileresolver.cpp:57:
/usr/include/sqlite3.h:4493: error: expected initializer before'__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_2_0_DEP__IPHONE_5_0'
make[3]: *** [../o/hugefileresolver.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [gml-target] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sublibs] Error 2
make: *** [ogr-target] Error 2
```

I've been trying to figure this out for weeks now, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check this : GDAL is building with a 64 bit option turned on. To turn that off, use the --with-unix-stdio-64=no flag.

Comment: I tried it, but it makes no difference, it gives the same error :|