# create gdal static library for xcode 9 (libgdal.a)

Tags: ios, xcode, gdal

I need to create a gdal static library (libgdal.a) to use it in iOS. I tried this script [Incorporating GDAL/OGR into an iOS project - A quick guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643898/incorporating-gdal-ogr-into-an-ios-project-a-quick-guide) but it just work for iOS 6. And I also tried https://gist.github.com/lachlanhurst/745e1e1d196c3e697450 but I got a lot of warnings and errors and this script didn't generate the libgdal.a. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you finally manage to solve this? I am facing the same issue.