# how to get location info from geoPDF in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation, geospatial, gdal

I need to get the location info from `geoPDF` to use it on an iPhone. I am trying to use `gdal` but I'm not succeeding in generating the static library for that. Any alternatives?

Comment: It would be nice to add code that you have tried so that we can help more.

Comment: Please, check the link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52124407/create-gdal-static-library-for-xcode-9-libgdal-a) in order to see my attempts to create a static library.